# Using ArrayFixture with a list of objects containing nested non-primitive objects

Tags: java, fitnesse

I am using [ArrayFixture](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.FitLibraryFixtures.ArrayFixture) to verify lists of non-primitive objects that contain other non-primitives. I have a simple setup like this:

```
public class Car {
  public String getName();
  public Details getDetails();
  ...
}

public class Details {
  public String getMake();
  ...
}
```

With ArrayFixture, all you need to do is call `setActualCollection(yourListOfObjects)` in the constructor of the class.

How do I reference the elements in the object's non-primitive variables? This is how my Fitnesse test looks:

```
|Verify Cars|
|name   | details Make | ... |
|Taurus | Ford         | ... |
|...    | ...          | ... |
```

I have been able to easily use the ArrayFixture when the object in the list contains primitive objects, but I haven't found any documentation on how to handle non-primitive elements.

Comment: A workaround would be to transfer these complex objects into simple objects (containing only primitives) that are built around the fixture. I'd prefer to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayFixture uses the column headings as method names to execute on the objects in your collection, so you'd need methods on Car to access the details you want to check:

```
public class Car {
  public String getMake() { return getDetails().getMake(); }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mike. I don't want to change any production code for fit testing so it looks like I will have to do that workaround.

Comment: Or you can use a wrapper class that exposes the fields you want for testing.